# How did early coal power plants generate DC?

Tags: dc, power-generation

It seems that the early coal power plants used a similar method that is used in modern times, with magnets and wire coils. This method generates AC, but the early power plants used DC, so how did they generate DC?

Comment: have you done any research?

Comment: Especially research on DC generators.

Comment: ... a.k.a. "dynamos"

Comment: the biggest push on coal power plants is in DC ( Washington) (j/k )   It is easy to convert AC to DC but expensive to convert DC to AC, so if you were going to pick one or the other AC would be the better choice.

Comment: [History of Electricity](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/29136.History_of_Electricity)?

Comment: The output slip-rings, solid in the case of AC generators, are cut into pieces for DC generators, to provide automatic polarity correction as the rotor rotates.

Comment: changed the title to reflect your question!

Answer (score 3):

So fundamentally, the AC generator and DC generator are the same. The predominant difference is how the terminals are attached to the armature. AC generators will utilize slip rings between terminals and rotor, this means that the voltage passed onto the terminals will be AC. DC generators have a mechanical rectification device called the [Commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_(electric)). The commutator rectifies the AC voltage that is produced in the rotor to a pulsing DC voltage at the terminals.

That's kind of a quick summary of how it's done. But you can read more into if you desire a deeper understanding.